# how to deal with the current data when zoom in and out

Tags: html, canvas

How to make sure the canvas of chart-line can be zoomed in and out with the mouse position when the mouse wheel scrolls?

In my canvas of chart-line, I am not using chart.js or d3.js, or other libraries. I'm expecting it could be zoomed in and out around the mouse position，but the values change with zoom in and out.How to make sure the center point-the mouse position- would not be influenced by the changing of the coordinate system.

Comment: are you using `transform: scale()` to zoom in and out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CSS `transform` property `scale()` then you can set another rule called `transform-origin`. If you set it to the center of the screen before applying the `scale()` then the page will zoom in correctly.

```
// performs the change of origin and scales the body element
zoom(scale, mouse) {

    return $('body').css('transformOrigin', getMouse(mouse))
        .css('transform', 'scale('+scale+')');

}

// returns a string of the current center of screen
getMouse() {
    let midX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let midY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    let x = $('body').css('left').split('p')[0];
    let y = $('body').css('top').split('p')[0];

    return String(midX - x + 'px ') + String(midY - y + 'px');
}
```

Then you can implement the scroll activation with the `bind()` method:

```
let scale = 1;
let scrollFactor = -0.1;
$(window).bind('wheel mousewheel', function(e){

    let scroll = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
    let sign = Math.sign(scroll);
    let newScale = Math.round((scale + scrollFactor * sign)*100)/100;

    // you could set an if statement here before calling zoom() to
    // set a lower and higher zoom limit
    zoom(newScale, [e.pageX, e.pageY]);


});
```

Comment: I'm not using CSS and transform. 

I'm doing the history data of chart-line， by changing the spacing between the two points of the chart-line and redrawing it to get the result of zoom in and out. I want make a demo like this: https://app.expertoption.com/ 

I almost finish my demo, except this-I don't konw how to deal with the current data that can make it zoome in and out with the mouse position. I just make it  zoomed in and out with the left side of the screen.

Comment: Well if you don't give some detailed information **and some code**, we can't help you

Comment: Ok！Thankyou anyway ：)

Comment: You can edit your question to give more details so we can help you